# ls command to exclude certain files

Tags: command-line, ls

Can some one please help me write an `ls` command to list files starting with abc (`abc*.txt`) and exclude the ones containing `_DEL_` in the name (`abc*_DEL*.txt`)

I am trying something like this:

```
ls abc*.txt --ignore "abc*_DEL_*.xt"
```

Comment: `GLOBIGNORE='*_DEL_*'; ls abc*.txt`, or `shopt -s extglob; ls abc*!(_DEL_).txt`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `ls -w 1 abc*.txt|grep --invert-match --regexp=DEL`

ls output all matched files, one per line. grep filters files with "DEL" case sensitive.

Example:

```
leonid@LeonidMew:~$ ls -w 1 *.txt
abc123.txt
abc222.txt
abc_333.txt
abc_DEL.txt
bbb111.txt
ccc111.txt
leonid@LeonidMew:~$ ls -w 1 abc*.txt|grep --invert-match --regexp=DEL
abc123.txt
abc222.txt
abc_333.txt
```

Updated: based on comments:
this may help: Try this `ls -1 abc*.txt|grep -v -e DEL`
Note glob abc* is for shell command line, if you need it in script then different way of usage needed.(i.e. running shell to parse a command from script)

Comment: Error 

Message: [Pre/Post Session Command] Process id 18350206. Standard output and error:
grep: Not a recognized flag: -
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] -e pattern_list...
 [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L]  [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] [-e pattern_list...]
 -f pattern_file... [file...]
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] pattern_list [file...]
ls: Not a recognized flag: w
Usage: ls [-1ACFHLNRSabcdefgiklmnopqrstuxEUX] [File...]

Comment: This for ubuntu. May be possible to find similar options in your linux. -w for ls is output in one column, because grep will work with each line separately after that. About grep, if it not possible to find similar, I can write regexp what will "invert match".

Comment: Try this `ls -1 abc*.txt|grep -v -e DEL`